# Nuclear holocaust survival?

Tags: apocalypse, post-apocalypse, nuclear, nuclear-war, nuclear-winter

Okay, so I'm writing a story about a character in one of the rebuilt cities of the world about 2000 years after a mass nuclear war that took place around maybe 100 years from now, a war that destroyed almost all cities with the first blasts, and the rest were destroyed in the firestorms.

I'm wondering, how different would these rebuilt societies be compared to societies nowadays, and, in what way will the nuclear war have affected the earth as a whole, like with nuclear winter and all that, would there still be much smoke?

How would a group of maybe 1000 or so people be able to survive a mass war of that type for so long?

I'm trying to make all of this as realistic as possible~ So this story isn't directly post-apocalyptic, but it's more about a story in a rebuilt city 2000 or so years after the war. Any help or criticism or anything would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey @cclive10, welcome. Did you take the site [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)? IMHO, this question falls under "Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer" and so it isn't well suited to the site as it stands currently...

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! This is, by the looks of it, an extremely broad question, so you might want to [edit] your question so it only asks one specific question, instead of several broader questions. Looking through questions and answers on the various tags you've used might be able to help narrow things down a bit

Comment: You have three questions here.  The third could be all right, but it's subsequent to the second.  The first would be Too Broad on its own.  I would stick with "How would a group of maybe 1000 or so people be able to survive a mass war of that type for so long?" and get rid of the other two.  You can ask the third after getting answers to that.  Note that a thousand people will not survive for a hundred years.  They'll have to have great-great-grandkids who survive for them.

Comment: You might want to read the book lucifer's hammer by larry niven, it is literally about how a town survives something similar, an asteroid impact. The biggest issue is the preservation of knowledge and skills.

Comment: Suggested viewing: Threads. Although, this film covers a much smaller time frame: cold-war turns hot until roughly a generation post nuclear exchange, this film goes to great lengths to come up with a relatively plausible scenario. This movie, implies the bad things happening rather that showing them, which makes it even more terrifying. https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2018/01/sleep-no-more-threads-is-coming-to-blu-ray/

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that, in a war 100 years from now, your best bet would be to have the survivors on a space outpost - say the moon, Mars, or a space station. When the earth cools down, they come back down.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/39903)

Comment: The question "How would a group of maybe 1000 or so people be able to survive a mass war of that type for so long?" the answer 'Seek shelter on a space station or space settlement'.